# How to set custom discount on totals of product(type=bundle) price in cart. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, bundle-product

I want to set custom price to bundle product. especially apply to the main product, not its options product. I need to apply the discount on the bundle's total price.

Here is my code working for the normal product type. it's properly working.

```
  /**
     * @param type $item
     *
     * @return true
     */
    protected function setItemPrice($item, $price) {
        $item->getProduct()->setSpecialPrice($price);
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can apply price to bundle product programmatically.

```
$product = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class);

$product->setSku('bundle-csec'); // Set your sku here       
$product->setName("Bundle Csec"); // Name of Product
$product->setAttributeSetId(4);
$product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
$product->setWeight('75'); // weight of product
$product->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
$product->setTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_BUNDLE);
**$product->setPrice('75');** // price of product
$product->setPriceView(0);
$product->setCustomAttribute('description', "Here is your prod description");
```

Let me know if that worked for you.